# Pass an argument on event change using http post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap ON/OFF switches to send an http post request on the event change. Whenever a switch changes its state from ON to OFF or OFF to ON, an http post request is triggered. Yes, it is working. However, I am not sure how to pass an argument through the http post function ($.post).

The update_state.php file takes in the argument 'state'. For example, update_state.php?state=ON will change the value of state field in the database.

The code I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('input[name="onoffswitch"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
          console.log(state); // true | false
          $.post("update_state.php",
            {
                state: "state"
            },
            function(data, status){
                console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        });
</script>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php

require_once("mysqli_connect.php");

if (!$database) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!" . PHP_EOL;

$state = $_GET['state'];

$sql = "UPDATE devices SET state='$state' WHERE id=1";

if (mysqli_query($database, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($database);
}

mysqli_close($database);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[name="onoffswitch"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    console.log(state); // true | false
    $.post( "update_state.php", { state: state }) // here { state: state } means {parameter-name: parameter-value}
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
});
```

Comment: A little hiccup. $.post doesnt work however, $.get works. Any ideas?

Comment: any erorr in console in $.post() ??

Comment: Nope. It loads the php file with a success. However, the sql query doesn't update the state field in the database. It clears it out.

Comment: I updated my OP with the php code. Have a look please.

Comment: ok try to fetch data using `$_POST['stat']`, as you are using post request :) do not use  `$_GET['stat']`

Comment: WOW!! I didn't realize that. Thanks a lot. Yes, that fixed it.